# Recieved multiple copies of the Stack Overflow email newsletter

Tags: bug, email, newsletter

Yesterday I received 2 copies of the Stack Overflow newsletter to the same email address (my profile email).

One is 180kb, the other is 183kb, both were received at 2:35 PM Eastern (18:35 UTC).

Comment: Yeah, same here for few months, not consistent. For me it's the Meta newsletter, so it's not specific to a single newsletter.